# Opening of new page by hyperlink using get method in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have two input named uin and order date these two field fetch the data from a table.Second field is depends on th value of first field and  the value of second field is fetched using ajax.There is one button (Generate)hyperlink  which navigates to new page viewstationerypdf.php  carrying the value selected in these two field.When i click on this button it does not react it is not taking me into new page .Data is fetching in both the input field .My code is-

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label> UIN<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <select class="form-control" name="uin" id="uin">
    <option value=""> </option>
    <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT uin from  tblstationerystock group by uin order by uin asc";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $cnt=1;
    if($query->rowCount() > 0)
    {
    foreach($results as $result)
    {  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->uin);?>">
      <?php echo htmlentities($result->uin);?>
    </option>
    <?php }} ?>
  </select>
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label> ORDER DATE<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <select class="form-control" name="orderdate" id="orderdate" value="" ;>

  </select>
</div>

<a href="stationerypdf.php?uin=<?php echo $_POST[uin];?> & orderdate= <?php echo $_POST[orderdate];?> target="popup"  onclick="window.open('stationerypdf.php?uin=<?php echo $_POST[orderdate];?> & orderdate= <?php echo $_POST[orderdate];?> ,'popup','height=600,width=900 top=15 left=300,location=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no, scrollbars=no'); return false;" > GENERATE</a>
```

Ajax code is

```
<?php 
include('includes/config.php');
$uin = $_POST['uin'];
echo "<option>Select ORDER DATE</option>";
$sql = "SELECT orderdate from  tblstationerystock  WHERE uin=$uin group by orderdate";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{               ?>  
<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->orderdate);?>">
<?php echo htmlentities($result->orderdate);?>
</option>
 <?php }}
 ?>
```

Comment: You mismatched tags `<button><a></button></a>`. Just remove the button tag.

Comment: You've said "I have a form" but I don't see any `<form …>` in your HTML

Comment: @CedricCholley I have updated my code plz chk it now

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I have updated my code plz chk it now